# add another JVM to oracle

Tags: java, oracle11g, jasper-reports

I have an Oracle 11g database. The DB is shipped with JVM 1.5.

I need to run a program called `jasperstarter` from a SQL statement. The program is written in Java and I use its jar file to compile a jasper report file. I get the following exception when running it:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/cenote/jasperstarter/App (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0
Exception in thread "Root Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/cenote/jasperstarter/App (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:66)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java)
at oracle.aurora.vm.OracleRuntime$1.run(OracleRuntime.java:826)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.aurora.vm.OracleRuntime.classAndMethodForRunJava(OracleRuntime.java:800)
```

It appears that my JVM version is too old to run jasperstarter. Is there a way to upgrade it or add another JVM to the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Open any of the class files inside the JAR and look at byte offsets 4 through 7. These bytes give you the java version for which the class has been compiled FOR. If it is for JAVA 6+, then you need a Java 6/7 JRE to run it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Any Hex editor should help you to see those bytes in the class file

Comment: thanks ponmani for your reply ,
it's stated already on jasperstarter page that it requires java 1.6 or higher to run, so my problem now is to make the oracle db use a newer version of java.
https://bitbucket.org/cenote/jasperstarter/

Comment: You can use                                                                            /your_jre7_path/java -cp /opt/jasperstarter/lib/jasperstarter.jar de.cenote.jasperstarter.App                                                                                                    Replace /opt/jasperstarter/lib/ with your jasperstarter installation directory. Refer Invoking JasperStarter section of http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/usage.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that - aside from upgrade to 12c. Oracle db's JVM is slightly different. For example it's GC also kills abandoned threads. This JVM can not be replaced different one.

Comment: is there a way to use multiple jvm's on the same database ?
for example the user scott will have a dbms_java package that runs java 1.5 while user Henry has a dbms_java package that runs java 1.8.